# webpack only compile files with recent changes

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am working on a large codebase; I have multiple `src` files to compile. When I run `watch` or compile for production it will compile all files found in src. Which is exactly what webpack should do.

But I would like to compile only the files which have been recently changed instead of all the files. Is this possible?

Here's my webpack config

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const extractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const {VueLoaderPlugin} = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        clients:
            "./src/clients/Resources/vue-js/clients.js",
        dashboard:
            "./src/dashboard/Resources/vue-js/dashboard.js",
        mapView:
            "./src/mapView/Resources/vue-js/mapView.js",
        admin:
            "./src/admin/Resources/vue-js/admin.js"
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "js/[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "js/[name].js"
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    name: "vendor",
                    filename: "js/vue_bundle.js",
                    automaticNameDelimiter: "_",
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    chunks: "all",
                    priority: 1,
                    minChunks: 2,
                    minSize: 0
                },
            }
        },
        occurrenceOrder: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    presets: ["env"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                    // use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    use: "raw-loader!sass-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader!sass-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.ico$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.yaml$/,
                loader: "json-loader!yaml-loader"
            }
        ]
    },


    plugins: [
        new extractTextPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].css",
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: can you share code with src part?

Comment: @VadimHulevich 

Here's my entry src

```
    entry: {
        clients:
            "./src/clients/Resources/vue-js/clients.js",
        dashboard:
            "./src/dashboard/Resources/vue-js/dashboard.js",
        mapView:
            "./src/mapView/Resources/vue-js/mapView.js",
        admin:
            "./src/admin/Resources/vue-js/admin.js"
    },
```

Comment: i mean do you use `require` or  `import`?

Comment: i use import in my src files for importing files from node_modules only. This config for building only file with recent changes has nothing to do with require or import imo

Comment: That's correct, unless we see the webpack config, we can't really comment on how to speed it up :)

Comment: @AvinKavish I've added my webpack config. please advise

Comment: You should try two configs. One for development and one for production. Don't use optimisation for development.

Comment: @AvinKavish I already do that. This does not answer the question : how to compiled recently changed instead of all the files ?

Comment: If your development build is setup properly it will not compile all files, are you using webpack-dev-server? you can also try adding `cache-loader`

Comment: @AvinKavish no I am not using webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194811/discussion-between-avin-kavish-and-highflyingsmurfs).